# Проблема с задачей

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть задача:
В семье физика-нанотехнолога Дианы готовятся к наступлению Нового года. Чтобы полако- миться в новогоднюю ночь, Диана испекла для двух её лучших друзей — Вовы и Гриши — пирог в форме правильного многоугольника с n сторонами.
Тут она вспомнила, что Вове нравятся пироги в виде a-угольников (необязательно правильных), а Грише — пироги в виде b-угольников. Может ли Диана одним разрезом ножа разделить её пирог на две части, представляющие собой многоугольники ненулевой площади, в одном из которых a сторон, а в другом b сторон?
Примеры:

Ввод:
4
3
3
Вывод:
YES

Ввод:
4
4
4
Вывод:
YES

Мой код:

```py
cake = int(input())
cake1 = int(input())
cake2 = int(input())
if cake1 == cake2 or cake - cake1 - cake2 == 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

что не так?

Comment: а что собственно не так?

Comment: выводит что у меня ошибки(

Comment: и нам нужно догадаться, что за ошибки, что делает ваша программа, что это вообще за три числа? Вы автомеханику тоже будете говорить "какая-то неисправность" не уточная, где именно и в чем выражается?

Comment: @Эникейщик, по идее да - это автомеханик понимает как что там внутри работает, а для меня просто какой-то стук появился :)

Comment: @Zhihar ну да - что (стук) и где. А не просто привез в ремонт машину, поставил и ушел. Пусть сами ищут, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

начнем с того, что в вашей программе надо вводить 3 слова одно за другим через Ввод

а в примере требуется ввести все три числа одной строкой

поэтому

```
cake = int(input())
cake1 = int(input())
cake2 = int(input())
```

надо бы заменить на

```
cake, cake1, cake2 = map(int, input().split())
```

кроме того у вас одно из успешных условий выглядит как:

```
cake1 == cake2
```

а теперь представьте, что Вова и Гриша любят 3-угольные пироги, а Диана испекла 100-угольный пирог

ваше условие говорит, что 100-угольный пирог можно разделить на 2 3-угольные пирога

а это так?

Comment: да и второе условие неправильное. Количество углов в двух пирогах никогда не будет равно количеству углов в исходном пироге.